# Connecting LVDS signal from one PCB to another

Tags: pcb, connector, signal-integrity

I am tryin to connect LVDS signals on one PCB to another. I am using an FFC cable and am trying to understand if signal integrity would become an issue. The shortest FFC cable that I could find is 50mm and my signal frequency is 500Mhz. I also could not find the impedance of these FFC cables. I was wondering if there would  be any issues connecting these PCB's together using 0.5mm,50mm FFC cables.

Are there any other options to make connection between high speed LVDS signals on PCB?

Comment: It is probably possible to calculate the impedance if all the dimensions and materials are known; a link to a typical datasheet would be useful.

Comment: Is your FFC cable a single layer of conductors or is it two layers?

Comment: I've designed an LCD monitor and I've used a [shielded cable](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTKbntG05YY3Ld2TKWrNiVMpqbw3CpSYSkwjabusIML4vxjatMwRWfr6es) consisting of twisted pairs (0.15mm2 each) for transferring LVDS signals from the driver board to the LCD panel. Maximum frequency is probably around 373MHz (1920x1080x60x3) and I've seen no problems.  So I think you can use a cable like that.

Comment: What’s the characteristic impedance of said cable and your PCB layout?

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this you are usually better off designing a [FPC (Flex Printed Circuit)](https://www.tech-etch.com/flex/flex_design_guide.pdf). This way you can adjust trace widths, spacing, and dielectric thicknesses, giving you total impedance control. It will likely cost a little bit more, and you will have to learn how FPCs are manufactured so that you better understand how to design them, but it will be well worth the trouble.